# Store access token in sandbox or keychain

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS app should I be storing access tokens in keychain or /tmp in sandbox?

What are the pros and cons of both the approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to access token such as OAuth.

If this is something you are treating as a session token and not long-lived (IE: Refresing the same token to extend it's life) then not writing it down and just retaining in memory might be sufficient.

However, if you are considering persisting this token to a data store (such as a file), then you should just rely on the keychain VS trying to reinvent the wheel.

Apple has extensive documentation on security mechanisms and best practices:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security